# NodeJS Stream doesn't 'end'

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm creating two PassThrough streams for one calculating md5 and for aws sdk upload like this:

```
const etagStream = new PassThrough();
const uploadStream = new PassThrough();
// Immediately pipe the request to both streams
req.pipe(etagStream);
req.pipe(uploadStream);
```

I have a function the calculates the partHashes but it seems to hang in the for loop and I'm not sure why:

```
async function processStreamChunks(stream: Readable) {
const partSize = 5 * 1024 * 1024;
  let currentPartBuffer = Buffer.alloc(0);
  const partHashes: string[] = [];
  stream.on('data', (chunk) => console.log(`Received chunk: ${chunk.length} bytes`));
  stream.on('end', () => console.log('Stream ended'));
  stream.on('error', (err) => console.error('Stream error:', err));
  stream.on('close', () => console.log('Stream closed'));
  for await (const chunk of stream) {
    currentPartBuffer = Buffer.concat([currentPartBuffer, chunk]);

    while (currentPartBuffer.length >= partSize) {
      const part = currentPartBuffer.slice(0, partSize);
      currentPartBuffer = currentPartBuffer.slice(partSize);
      const partHash = calculateMD5Hash(part);
      partHashes.push(partHash);
    }
  }

  // Handle any remaining data in the buffer as the last part
  if (currentPartBuffer.length > 0) {
    const partHash = calculateMD5Hash(currentPartBuffer);
    partHashes.push(partHash);
  }

  return partHashes;
}
```

In the logs all i see is Received chunk: 63794 bytes

Comment: Try removing all of the `stream.on` statements, log chunk receipt in the `for` loop, and handle errors with a catch clause on the async function's returned promise.